# how to control jquery UI menu sub item and parent item arranging bottom to bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, menu

the position of jquery ui menu items is top to top, as displayed below:
[image]

but I want to change it to bottom aligned, is anyone know that?

Comment: Can you create a demo? And please do not hesitate to post the codes.

Comment: I can not find a demo on web, I want to arrange the sub items from bottom to top, and the bottom of sub element and the bottom of the parent element is Horizontal

Comment: please put ur code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can answer your question.

Comment: Hi, I have found one solution: `$( "#menu" ).menu({ position: { my: "bottom",  at:"right+105 top+25"} });`